# Why does this DateTime fail to parse without a comma?

Tags: datetime, scratch-org

One of my tests creates a `DateTime` object like this:

```
DateTime.parse('2/19/2024 4:30 PM')
```

In a scratch org, this throws an exception: `System.TypeException: Invalid date/time: 2/19/2024 4:30 PM`. I see I have to add a comma to fix the format. This works:

```
DateTime.parse('2/19/2024, 4:30 PM')
```

However, why does the first version does not cause any problems in my developer org?
The test class is using API v46.
Both orgs have the same locale. Both orgs do have the ["Enabled ICU Locale Formats critical update"](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_forcecom_globalization_enable_icu_cruc.htm&type=5&release=224) **disabled** as far as I can tell. What is going on? Are there any other settings that I should be aware of that change the date format?

The only other thing I can think of is that ICU locale format is in fact **enabled** in the scratch org even though it still shows up in `Setup->Release Updates`.

Comment: do you have the same user locale in developer org and scratch org? `DateTime.parse` respects user locale.

Comment: What do you mean by "User Locale" @OleksandrBerehovskyi? If you mean User.LocaleSidKey then yes, both users have the same locale. There is really nothing special about the scratch org and the development org, they both are org with a US locale. The only "special" thing is that the dev org has been created many years ago and might have some old settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per critical updates documentation, orgs created in Winter 20 or later have ICU locale format automatically enabled. It makes sense that scratch org is throwing this error.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_forcecom_globalization_enable_icu_cruc.htm&type=5&release=224

Comment: nice, thanks for sharing!